# Temporary SQL server for tests

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, testing, automated-tests

I'm writing a Node.js module that generates MySQL statements, and I want to run it against a test suite.

I want to start up an SQL server (don't mind which, but MySQL seems easiest to set up across all platforms) for the duration of the tests, and then shut it down again.

What is the best way to do this?  Is there a neat way that doesn't conflict with a MySQL instance already running on the machine?

---

***EDIT*** for clarification:

I'm not looking to get a single instance up and running - I can do that fairly easily.  I am looking for a scriptable way to start and stop an SQL server on the local machine, so that any other developer can run the tests without configuration.

Comment: Hmm, if you are bothered taking this route, you could create a free website on the likes of Hostinger and you'll have free reign without being able to break anything local to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

I like the fact that your question was `What is the best way?` instead of `the easy way`.

There are two ways to do this, with `Vagrant` and with `Docker`.

**Vagrant**

You can have a mysql installed inside your vagrant machine and use it for development purposes. You could read more about `Vagrant` [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/).

Here are the steps that you should follow in order to have a `Vagrant` machine up and running (I hope you already read the documentation at this point).

1. **Install vagrant**: That will depend on your operative system. You can download it [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html).
2. **Initialize your vagrant machine**: You can create a new vagrant machine with `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32` command inside your desired folder.
3. **Edit your configuration file**: The next step is edit you `Vagrantfile`, you can have a vagrant machine without editing it but just check every option and see if it it your needs. Maybe you need to change the `ip` and `port` of your vagrant machine.
4. **Start your vagrant machine**: You can do this with a simple `vagrant up`.
5. **Connect to your vagrant machine**: you can do `vagrant ssh` inside your folder that contains your `Vagrantile` and you'll now be connected to your vagrant machine.
6. **Install things**: This is a very extensive step but the easy way is that you can install anything inside your vagrant, `mysql` for example. And if you want to learn more you should read about `vagrant + puppet` and how to provision your vagrant machine in an automatic way.

**Docker**

You can have a container with mysql installed inside. Almost the same case if compare it with `Vagrant` but the infrastructure is complete different and is another concept. This one is newer and you could use it on production. You can read more [here](https://www.docker.com/).

When you read more about `docker`, you could use [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) container.

You can follow this steps in order to have a docker container up and running.

1. **Install docker toolbox**: You can download it from [here](https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox).
2. **Pull the container you need**: Just run `docker pull mysql` and you will have a machine running with mysql.

You can read the documentation (I strongly recommend that) in order to know about opening ports and find the docker ip.

Talking about this topics is very extensive, but also very useful, if you learn about this two things, not only it will solve your problem but it will be useful for you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Mac then "Postgres.app" is the easiest way to have a PostgreSQL database on Mac. It puts up an icon that you can turn on/off the server. If you are explicitly looking for mySQL then sorry.